# Convertir ASCII en binario en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, conversión-de-tipos, ascii

Tengo un problema intentando convertir ASCII en binario. En efecto, estoy traduciendo una trama AIS (que sirvé por la navegación en buques) simbolo por simbolo sobre seis bits a partir de 15 (donde empieza la carga útil). Y a pesar de haber `!AIVDM,1,1,,A,15O86n001TJ3KutH8ar@<h;l06Hh,0*5D` la traducción esta por cada simbolo:  `1100001`.

Aqui la carga util es: `15O86n001TJ3KutH8ar@<h;l06Hh`

```
Public Sub decodage_AIS(tramaAs String)
    Dim coleccion_ASCII(trames.ToString.Length) As String
    Dim variable As Char
    Dim binaryDigits() As Char

    For i = 15 To tableau_ASCII.Length - 1
        variable = trama(i)
        equivalent_byte = equivalent_byte + System.Convert.ToString(Asc(variable), 2).PadLeft(4, "0")
        binaryDigits = equivalent_byte.ToCharArray
        My.Application.DoEvents()
    Next
```

por ejemplo, **`1` debe ser convertido en `000001` pero esta convertido en `1100001` como todos los otros simbolos, `5` en `000101` esta convertido en `1100001`.**

Finalmente, espero esta conversion:

```
1       000001
5       000101
O       011111
8       001000
6       000110
n       110110
0       000000
0       000000
1       000001
T       100100
J       011010
3       000011
K       011011
u       111101
t       111100
8       001000
a       101001
r       111010
@       010000
<       001100
h       110000
;       001011
l       110100
0       000000
6       000110
H       011000
h       110000
```

He leido la repuesta de user3947014 y tambien esta de Pradeep Kumar por la pregunta [Convert from string to binary vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404993/convert-from-string-to-binary-vb-net)

**Pienso que el problema viene de `variable = trama(i)**`

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? No lo acabo de ver. Podrías darnos un ejemplo de Input y Output? :) Dado este Input: `!AIVDM,1,1,,A,15O86n001TJ3KutH8ar@<h;l06Hh,0*5D` cuál es la salida que esperas?

Comment: @MiquelColl, he editado ;)

Comment: Estás **seguro** que 1 es `000001`? http://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.htm Quieres tratar el `1` cómo número o como `char`?

Comment: @MiquelColl Quiero tratar el `1` cómo `char` y estoy seguro qye 1 es `000001`

Answer (score 1):

Partiendo de coger cada valor como un `char` como ya tienes definido en la variable `variable` (¡qué original! Hehe):

```
Dim binaryCharCode As String
binaryCharCode = Convert.ToString(variable, 2)
```

Lo que hace este `ToString(char c, int i)` es básicamente transformar el `char` `c` en base `i`.

Por lo que veo con tu definición queires tratar los números en ese string cómo *números* en sí y no como un `char` por lo que es necesario comprobar en cada ciclo si el `char` con el que iteramos puede ser (o no) un número:

```
Dim num As Integer
If Not Integer.TryParse(variable, num) Then
    num = -1
End If
```

Ahora si la variable `num` es distinta a `-1` significa que tenemos un número y sinó tenemos una letra (o otra cosa):

```
If num = -1 Then
    'Tratamos cómo número
Else
    'Tratamos como char
End If
```

Para juntarlo todo (junto a tu código):

```
Dim coleccion_ASCII(trames.ToString.Length) As String
Dim variable As Char
Dim equivalent_byte As String

For i = 15 To tableau_ASCII.Length - 1
    variable = trama(i)
    Dim num As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(variable, num) Then
        num = -1
    End If
    If num = -1 Then
        equivalent_byte = equivalent_byte + Convert.ToString(num, 2)
    Else
        equivalent_byte = equivalent_byte + Convert.ToString(variable, 2)
    End If
Next
My.Application.DoEvents()
```

Destacar que tenías **dentro** de tu loop el `DoEvents` y debería ir fuera (si no me equivoco).